# Can I "drag" a file into a window without a file manager?

Tags: x11, file-manager, drag-and-drop

(I'm on Arch Linux, using i3 as my wm and xterm as my terminal emulator, though I don't know if any of that is relevant.)

Occasionally, a website asks me to drag a file with my mouse from my desktop into the internet browser's window. Almost always, there is an alternative, but recently I found something I want to do that requires the drag and drop. Unfortunately, I don't have a file manager. I navigate my computer's file system solely through bash.

Is there a way I can fake the drag and drop action? Can I tell my browser "I just dropped this file onto you" without actually doing it?

Worst case scenario, I can download a graphical file manager exclusively to drop files into my web browser, but I'd like to avoid that solution.

Comment: > Can I tell my browser "I just dropped this file onto you" without actually doing it?"

Sounds like a great question for the javascript community on stackexchange.

Comment: Also see [www:mechanize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382788/post-forms-and-upload-files-using-linux-command-line) or a derivative. There is perl and python it seems. The more solutions the better!

Comment: Related: [How do I install userscripts in Chrome on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/how-do-i-install-userscripts-in-chrome-on-linux)

Comment: dragbox doesn't exist anymore. please change your accepted answer.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay done, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem a few months back and ultimately just wrote a tool to do it for me. When I saw this and found someone else had the same itch I cleaned it up so that someone other than me could actually get it running, and finished off my to-do list. The code is up now: https://github.com/mwh/dragon

To get it, run

```
git clone https://github.com/mwh/dragon.git
cd dragon
make
```

That will give you a standalone `dragon` executable - you can move it wherever you want. `make install` will put it in `$HOME/.local/bin`.

Either way, you can then:

```
dragon *.jpg
```

to get a simple window with draggable buttons for each of those files:

[image: Screenshot of dragon showing a few files]

You can drag any of those into a browser, a file manager, an editor, or anywhere else that speaks the standard drag-and-drop protocol.

If you want to go the other way, and drag things **in** to it, use `--target` — they'll be printed to standard output, or available to drag out again with if you use `--keep` as well.

---

To build you'll need a C compiler and the GTK+ 3 development headers - if you're on Arch you'll get those just by installing GTK+, but on other distributions you may have to `apt-get install build-essentials libgtk3-dev` or `yum install gtk3-devel` or similar first. Other than that it's entirely self-contained, with no constituent libraries or anything, and you can just put the executable where you want.

My use case is mostly one-off drags of only a few files (usually just one), without particularly caring how they show up, so if that doesn't line up with what you want then Dragbox (which I didn't see until recently) might still be better for you. Just yesterday I added the support for using it as a drag target as well, so that part hasn't had much use on my end. Other than that, though, I've been using this successfully for a while now. There are other modes and options described in the readme file.

Comment: Thank you! It took seconds to build/install! I'll use that! The --target option is a blast!

Comment: Nice, small, standalone binary. With nice small Makefile. Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You are a hero. This tool is also available on the AUR under the name `dragon-drag-and-drop-git`.

Comment: I love you! arch community loves U! thank you! I had been searching for this for ages.

Comment: For me it was `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev` then `make` and `make install`. Works great.

Comment: FWIW, `nnn` (the terminal-based file manager) has [a plugin for `dragon`](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/blob/master/plugins/dragdrop).

Answer (score 30):

Thanks to @derobert for recommending the Dragbox application to me.

[Dragbox](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/dragbox) does exactly what I need. For example, I have a folder with a number of .png files that I would like to be able to drag into Chromium. Inside that folder, executing `dragbox *.png` creates this window:

[image: A GUI window with the names of several files listed]

I can use my mouse to drag files from there into Chromium, and it works flawlessly. However, getting to this point was a pain. As far as I am aware, Dragbox only officially supports Debian systems. I couldn't find it anywhere that natively worked for Arch. So, I've written a step-by-step guide to getting Dragbox working in Arch Linux. This is almost exactly what I did on my machine, with a couple modifications to follow better practices. If there's an error somewhere, you can look in this answer's edit history to see *exactly* what I did on my machine.

1. Clone Dragbox's source to your computer by executing `git clone https://github.com/engla/dragbox.git`
2. There will be a new directory called `dragbox` created inside your current working directory. Go inside.
3. Dragbox and Dragbox's installation require Python 2, which comes standard on Arch Linux. However, it expects Python 2 to be the default Python installation, which isn't true on Arch. Get around this by executing `export PYTHON=/bin/python2`. Until you close your current terminal window, the environment variable `$PYTHON` will have the value `/bin/python2`. Dragbox's installation scripts check for that, and will use it over Python 3.
4. Execute `./autogen.sh`, `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. `make install` must be done with root privileges (e.g. `sudo make install`).
5. Dragbox is now installed on your computer, but is going to try to use Python 3 to run. With root privileges, open `/usr/local/bin/dragbox` in a text editor. Modify the shebang (the first line, that tells your shell what executable to run the script with) from `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python2`.
6. The script is now working, but it can't find the module containing the actual program. There are a couple of ways you can fix this.

   1. Include in your `~/.bashrc` or similar a line reading `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:` immediately (as in, not even a space between) followed my the path to a directory. Python will now look in that directory when trying to import modules. Inside the directory created back in step 1, there will be a directory called `Dropbox/` (with a capital D). Copy that directory to the directory you added to your `$PYTHONPATH` (e.g. if you wrote `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/python/modules`, copy the `Dragbox/` directory to create `~/python/modules/Dragbox/`).
   2. Probably worse practice, but you can copy that same directory to a directory already in your `$PYTHONPATH`. For example, you could copy it to create `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

If you've followed these steps, Dragbox should be working! You can now execute `man dragbox` to learn more about how to use it, and launch it by simply typing `dragbox`.

Comment: Actually, using `/usr/bin/env python2` is the recommended way these days, since [PEP 394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) got adopted.

Comment: You don't need the second fix. Simply copy the `Dragbox` directory into the `PYTHONPATH` somewhere (like in the *python2* `site-packages`, either system or per-user). That line is executed only when `dragbox` cannot import that package.

Comment: @Seth Well, thanks I guess. I made a python script run on a *slightly* different system than it was designed for, that still had python on it :P I'm glad it was python, though, since that's the only language I'm fluent enough in to have made this happen.

Comment: @Gilles To be honest, I will probably never touch that file again, but if I do I'll fix that :P I'll edit it into my answer, though, in case someone else sees it and copies me. Thanks!

Comment: @Bakuriu Like I told Gilles, it doesn't matter enough to me for it to be worth fixing, but I'll edit it into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: With Archlinux, the real solution for this type of thing is to wrtie a [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pkgbuild). You largely do what you've done, but you put it into a special script that allows `pacman` to manage the files for you so you don't ever have to go mucking around in the system should you want to update or remove it.

Comment: @HalosGhost That may be the case, but I would have had to learn something. :P

Comment: Dragbox seems to be dead. The git-repo is gone.

Comment: The link in this answer doesn't seem to work, either. This is unfortunate, since it sounds like this is exactly the utility I was looking for. It looks like it was part of Ubuntu once upon a time, but now I can't find it anywhere. ☹ http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dragbox.1.html

Answer (score 9):

Just solved the issue myself.

Quite possibly the easiest way is to use the "Open file..." dialog.
You can simply drag and drop from the gtk file dialog, just like a file manager.

You may need to open a separate window to make sure the dialog doesn't steal the screen.

That's it. That easy.

Comment: Awesome! No need to install anything. I'm using Firefox so I cannot click the menu, but Ctrl+o works just fine.

Comment: Words cannot express the awesomeness of this answer!

Answer (score 7):

You can easily navigate the filesystem within your browser, using the syntax:

```
file:///home/username/blah/blah
```

Open the path in an empty tab and from there you can drag and drop your file.
At least with chrome/chromium, don't have other browsers here to try.

Comment: This isn't working for me, but I can't tell if it's a problem with the method you describe or a problem with the userscript that wants me to drop stuff in...

Comment: I think there's a command line switch or a attribute within chrome you have to enable to allow this.

Comment: Would `chrome://flags` be the right place to look for something like this? That's where I'm looking at the moment.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail mmm you're right, I just tried with the demo at http://www.dropzonejs.com/ and it doesn't work. Could definitively be a permission problem, though

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can start the GTK file dialog using a command line tool like `zenity` and drag'n'drop from there.

Example:

```
zenity --file-selection
```