# Does an app with the functionality of Dropzone 3 exist in Linux?

Tags: desktop, drag-and-drop

(currently for macOS)

> Dropzone 3 also includes what’s called a Drop Bar feature. This enables users to drag one or more files onto the Drop Bar icon where they can be parked for later retrieval. Source #2
>
> For example, you can select file on your desktop and drag onto a Dropzone action that can or copy the file to a designated folder in your Finder. Other actions allow you to drop and send a file to your printer, upload an image to ImageShack or Imgur, or copy a file to your public Dropbox account. Source #2

- https://aptonic.com #1
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dropzone-3-turbocharges-mac-drag-drop-actions/ #2

[image]

Comment: Do the tools from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137905/can-i-drag-a-file-into-a-window-without-a-file-manager) do what you want?

Comment: @MichaelHomer They fulfill a part of the job (visual clipboard), but not none seem to offer "actions" that can pass lists of dropped items to scripts ("Other actions allow you to drop and send a file to your printer, upload an image to ImageShack or Imgur, or copy a file to your public Dropbox account.").